# Ola Hallegren Index and Statistics Maintenance Does not Appear to be Working

Tags: sql-server

Here are the settings I am using when calling the proceudre:

```
EXECUTE Master.dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 30,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 50,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

The job runs fairly quickly and when I look at the fragmentation in my databases, there are many above the 50% level and some in the high 90% range. I am not sure how I can troubleshoot this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it was due to the page count of the indexes being less than 1,000. Apparently you can change this setting if you need to.